# SVG Background Flickering Once on Hover

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a button with a svg background that has also has an svg background for its hover. When I hover over it for the first time after the page loads, there is a flicker, but there is no flicker on any subsequent hover. I thought this may be a loading issue, but even if I load both images on the page independently or pre-load the images, this flicker still occurs so it isn't a loading issue. What is going on?

```css
.minus{
    background: url(https://www.svgrepo.com/show/294589/shuffle-random.svg);
background-size: cover;
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
}

.minus:hover{
    background: url(https://www.svgrepo.com/show/240096/shuffle-random.svg);
}
```

```html
<button class="minus">
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Comment: @Paulie_D Sorry about that! Fixed- thank you for the info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because hidden elements / assets are not loaded (inactive selectors or `display: none`, etc). You have to preload it manually.

Here are some ideas:

> Note: The server https://www.svgrepo.com/ sometimes responds with 403 Forbidden. So you probably see no images. (See console)

### Preload with CSS

```css
.minus {
  background: url(https://www.svgrepo.com/show/294589/shuffle-random.svg);
  background-size: cover;
  border: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.minus:hover {
  background: url(https://www.svgrepo.com/show/240096/shuffle-random.svg);
}

body:after {
  /* display: none -- does not work anymore due to latest optimizations.*/
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  content: url(https://www.svgrepo.com/show/240096/shuffle-random.svg);
}
```

```html
<button class="minus"></button>
```

This is just one way of doing it. It may depend on your framework. You could also do this in JavaScript (load images). Or think different: Use a tiled sprite as (one) image and just move the background position on hover. Or just load both at once.

### Use sprites

```css
.minus {
  background: 
    url(https://www.svgrepo.com/show/294589/shuffle-random.svg),
    url(https://www.svgrepo.com/show/240096/shuffle-random.svg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 0, 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  border: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.minus:hover {
  background-position: 0;
}
```

```html
<button class="minus"></button>
```

### Preload images in HTML

```css
.minus {
  background: url(https://www.svgrepo.com/show/294589/shuffle-random.svg);
  background-size: cover;
  border: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.minus:hover {
  background: url(https://www.svgrepo.com/show/240096/shuffle-random.svg);
}

#preload {
  /* In this case / context display hidden works. */
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="preload">
  <img src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/240096/shuffle-random.svg">
</div>

<button class="minus"></button>
```

### Preload images in JavaScript

```js
[
  'https://www.svgrepo.com/show/294589/shuffle-random.svg',
  'https://www.svgrepo.com/show/240096/shuffle-random.svg',
].forEach((imageUrl) => {
  new Image().src = imageUrl;
});
```

```css
.minus {
  background: url(https://www.svgrepo.com/show/294589/shuffle-random.svg);
  background-size: cover;
  border: 0;
  display: block;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
}

.minus:hover {
  background: url(https://www.svgrepo.com/show/240096/shuffle-random.svg);
}
```

```html
<button class="minus"></button>
```

Search the web with keywords like: css background image hover blinks preload etc

Comment: Even if I load both images (hover and non-hover) on the page along side of the button before hovering, the flicker still occurs, and stated in the question this is not an issue of pre-loading the images.

Comment: @Hitokage Yes I have read it. But I reproduced your problem and found out that it _is_ a preload problem. You can reproduce it by reload this page before click on "Run code snipped". Your example is flickering. But all my examples has fixed the issue in different ways. But if this is still an issue for you, check out the "Use sprites" solution from this answer. This is a complete other way to solve this issue. Try it out and let me know if this solves your issue. I'm sure it will fix it. :)

Comment: I will have to eat my words - despite the fact I had in fact tried more than one pre-load method (including just putting them on the page), the last one with the javascript worked. Why wouldn't just putting them right on the page work, as that loads them immediately before you even hover?

Comment: I don't know your code and can't guess. Maybe you missed something? I tested all snippets on Chrome 97 and can reproduce your issue. For me, all my solutions works. Including the images-on-page one. Note that Chrome (and other browsers) has many optimizations to reduce data loading. E.g. hidden images with `display: none` or inactive selectors will not be loaded. ... Which framework do you use? I can take a look to your project if you have a repository (e.g. on GitHub). But glad to hear that one solution from my answer works for you. Consider clicking the ✓ for this answer if it was helpful.

Comment: I could reproduce the same problem just using a notepad file and opening it up in Chrome, without needing to be in a project, which is what led me to posting here as I've never seen this issue in all my years.

Comment: I feel you. I haven't had any problems with it either. So I was interested in solving this problem. Keep in mind that you are loading images from another domain. Which takes longer than local files to load. It's also similar to a game engine, where you have to preload images. Otherwise you'll run into the same issue. The browser does not automatically preload all possible assets (images) that you have in your application. For performance reasons and to reduce data traffic. Some frameworks may handle this issue automatically, so you don't have to worry about it. ...

Comment: ... But you can get around this problem by rethinking an implementation like the sprite solution. Which also comes from game development. Just place all the images you want in a row and crop to show just one. See again my example above and search the web for it. Either load all image urls you want. Put all the images together in a graphics program. For example: Download both images and place it togehter. Side by side. In css you just have to set the background size and position to just show one side. Left on idle and right on hover. ... Just one idea to work around the preloading problem.